# sklearn SGDClassifier fit() vs partial_fit()

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas

I am confused about `fit()` and `partial_fit()` method of `SGDClassifier`. Documentation says for both, "Fit linear model with Stochastic Gradient Descent.".

What I know about stochastic gradient descent is, it takes one (or a fraction of whole) training example to update parameters of model in one iteration. And gradient descent uses whole data set in each iteration. I want to train a model using logistic regression. I want to implement normal Gradient Descent and Stochastic gradient descent and compare time required for them. How to do that with `SGDClassifier`? Does `fit()` method works as normal gradient descent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `partial_fit` method is useful for updating a model that has already been trained, whereas the `fit` method will re-train the model from scratch.

As for manually selecting how much of the data is included in each weight update, I can't seem to find an argument for this in the [SGDClassifier documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html).

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. But both method uses stochastic gradient descent. Is that correct? If it is, then to implement gradient descent for logistic regression, I have to use LogisticRegression I think

Comment: Yeah to my knowledge both use SGD (they are both methods of the SGDClassifier after all!) - make sure to pay close attention to the `solver` you are using for LogisticRegression